# Приоритет в addListenr

Tags: javascript, click, listener

Вешаю события click на div, но проблема в том что на ему уже есть события, и мне нужно чтобы мое выполнилось первым. Подскажите можно ли так сделать, добавить свое события выше в очереди

Comment: Только если вешать его раньше чем другие. Либо попробовать использовать не фазу всплытия, а фазу захвата

Comment: поставьте сверху того дива, свой див и повесьте на него клик. Обработайте, а потом прокиньте

Comment: проблем в том что я могу только добавить скрипт в head или в конце страницы. Не могу не менять html либо что-то удалять

Comment: скриптом и добавьте. `document.createElement()`